# Coconut milk substitutions?

Tags: substitutions, coconut, coconut-milk

I am looking for a substitution for coconut milk. I am highly allergic to coconut, but often see recipes I would like to try that call for it.

Comment: Please provide details of why you need a substitute, and what type of recipes you want to substitute in.   It is far more difficult to give you a good answer in the abstract.   See:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-can-we-make-substitution-questions-more-helpful

Comment: I have no allergy, but always want to know about substitutes for everything. Maybe I run out of an ingredient. Maybe I just want to try an alternative to explore and mystify guests.

Answer (score 3):

You can use cow's milk with some grated coconut or coconut extract. Or because I just saw your allergy you can use equal parts of milk, sesame oil and molasses.

Answer (score 1):

You might make your own cashew milk, but I wouldn't recommend using commercially prepared ones, possibly with a bit less water than than most online recipes ... it tends to be thinned out to make them similar in viscosity as cow's milk, and coconut milk tends to be thicker.

Almond milk might work, but the same issues apply and it tends to be less viscous than cashew milk.  It's possible that grain based milks (such as oat milk) might work as well.